# Overriding save method in another class

Tags: python, django

I have a few models in project(modelA, modelB, modelC), and I want to override the save method in each so it has functionality applicable to all.

So I make something like this for a model:

```
class modelA(CustomClass, models.Model):
    ......

class CustomClass():
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        # and now I want to call modelA.save() method
        super(modelA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # super is used here as example
```

The question is if it is even possible, and if so, how can I do this ?

Comment: Is `CustomClass` supposed to be a common class between the types of model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just define your save method in the custom class and make sure you call the base method in any further overriding of the save method.

By default, the model uses the [`models.Model` implementation of `save`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L718). When you call super (via `super(CustomClass, self)..`) you will be invoking the usual saving behaviour.

---

Note the above depends on modelA inheriting from custom class which inherits from Model which I initially thought it was doing..

```
class modelA(CustomClass):
    ......

class CustomClass(models.Model):
    ....
```

Comment: Also thought about this, I think that doing something like models.Model.save(self, args, kwargs) in CustomClass.save is also applicable solution

Comment: @user3581394 - You are doing that anyway by invoking the base class' method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomClass(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do things needed generally 2.)
        super(CustomClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class ModelA(CustomClass):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do things specific for ModelA 1.)
        super(ModelA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # do things specific for ModelA 3.)
```

numbers before brackets show execution order in case of saving *ModelA*

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use mixins (composition-based multiple inheritance) for cases like this, but it's your call. It could be as simple as declaring a `CustomSaveMixin` class which inherits from `object`, with the `save` override you want. This would let you keep in place the base `Model` subclassing for the methods you don't need to override. For example:

```
class CustomSaveMixin(object):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        # If you're preserving existing Django save hooks (most likely).
        super(CustomSaveMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ExampleModel(models.Model, CustomSaveMixin):
    # ...
```

However, I haven't tried this approach (subclassing `object`), but I know it works for class based views. The official docs suggest declaring a mixin class that extends `models.Model`, but I'd try both approaches. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance